# Update user index failing using chewy gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I have a user in my Rails app that I am trying to manually index. In the console I am doing:

```
u=User.find 4317
User.update_index u
```

but the result of the index is:

```
irb(main):006:0> User.update_index u
=> [User(id: integer kind: string, login: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, public_name: string...
```

...notice the blank fields which makes me think the command did not run? Am I running the update_index command correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this. Based on my particular configuration I was able to simply update the user which caused it to be indexed. So:

```
u=User.find 4317
u.save
```